# What is "potential speedup" in parallel computing?

Tags: terminology, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, parallel-computing

There is an example problem from p506 of *Computer Organization and Design, Fifth Edition: The Hardware/Software interface by David A. Patterson, John L. Hennessy* 
 [image]

I wonder how "potential speedup" is defined? The book doesn't give its definition.

In the example, since speedup with $10$ processors is $55\%$ of the potential speedup, the potential speedup should be $ 5.5 / 55\% = 10$. it is equal to the number of processors.

Since the execution time before improvement has a part $(10t)$ unaffectable by parallel computing on multiple processors, according to Amdahl's law (outlined in blue box), the potential speedup must be smaller than the number of processors.

So I am puzzled.

Google books has an earlier (4th) edition which has [a similar example](https://books.google.com/books?id=3b63x-0P3_UC&lpg=PA52&dq=potential%20speedup%20%20amdahl%20law&pg=PA636#v=onepage&q&f=false) too.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 2):

*Potential speedup* $\equiv$ *number of processors*.  I agree that it is poorly chosen wording.  A better term would be *efficiency* (the average amount of time that the processors are doing useful work.)

Comment: Thanks. The execution time before improvement has a nonzero part (10t) unaffectable by parallel computing on multiple processors, and according to Amdahl's law (outlined in blue box), the speedup must be smaller than the number of processors. So how does "efficiency (the average amount of time that the processors are doing useful work)" take that into account?

Comment: Efficiency runs from 0 to 1.  1 - efficiency is the percentage of available processor time that went unused because only one processor was working.

Answer (score 1):

> Since the execution time before improvement has a part (10t)(10t)
>   unaffectable by parallel computing on multiple processors, according
>   to Amdahl's law (outlined in blue box), the potential speedup must be
>   smaller than the number of processors.

The potential speedup in the article means a number of processors, already answered. It means a speedup limit for a given PC for the case when the algorithm could be cut in parallel pieces unlimited.

For example, an algorithm has N independent parts for N processors. It never occurs in real life, but a theoretically example is - find N random numbers. Here our speedup is N, but the article's algorithm hasn't this property.

The Amdahl's law doesn't interfere directly with the potential speed term. It, in other words, states that when the task split, the summary execution time can't be less than the largest fragment. So, Amdahl's law uses only sequential computation time for program fragments as the statement objects, not a "potential speedup."

Answer (score 0):

Potential Speed up is how much we could have make it faster.
with 10 processor and total task size 110t (10t sequential and 110t parallelizable)
By Ahmdal's law

$$  Speedup_{curr} = \frac{T_{old}}{T_{new}} $$

And when would be the speedup be maximum. When every part is parallelizable. Then,

$$  T_{new} = \frac{T_{old}}{n} $$

$$  Speedup_{max} = \frac{T_{old}}{T_{new}} \\
            = n
$$

Thus potential speed up is

$$ Potential\: Speedup = \frac{Speedup_{curr}}{Speedup_{max}} \\
                     = \frac{Speedup_{curr}}{n}
$$

Answer (score 0):

With $p$ processors, you expect the solution to be obtained $p$ times faster, and this is of course the best you could hope.

This is indeed the *potential* speedup, and in practice it is never reached, due to overhead of parallelism and unavoidable parts of the algorithm that cannot be parallelized at all.

Things start going bad when the speedup stays below $1$. :-)